# How to compare email and password value from form with those in database and redirect to profile page if a match is found (MongoDB, Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm extremely new to backend development so sorry if this is a beginner question. Basically, I've been stuck with trying to create a simple, no authentication(for now) and no template api for users and link it to the frontend. I don't know where to start and I've been stuck at the login page (while also planning to make a registration & profile page after).

app.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('./models/user');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/user', 
    {
        useNewUrlParser:true,
        useUnifiedTopology:true
    });

mongoose.connection.on('error', ()=> {
    console.log('connection error')
});

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('We are now connected to our local MongoDB server')
});

app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);


//server initialization
app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('Now listening for requests on port 4000')
});
```

router

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const UserController = require('../controllers/user')

//retrieve all users
router.get('/', UserController.getAllUser);


//retrieve 1 user
router.get('/:userID', (req, res) => {
    UserController.getUser(req.params.userID).then(result => res.send(result))
})

//create new user
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    UserController.register(req.body).then(result => {
        if (result) {
            res.send(result)
        } else {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'server error'
            })
        }   
    })
})
 
//update user
router.put('/:userID', (req, res) => {
    UserController.updateUser(req.body, req.params.userID).then(result => res.send(result))
})

//delete user
router.delete("/:id", UserController.delete);

module.exports = router
```

controller

```
const User = require('../models/user.js');

//retrieve all users
module.exports.getAllUser = (req, res) => {
    User.find()
    .sort({ name: -1 })
    .then((users) => {
        res.status(200).send(users);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Error Occured",
        });
    });
}

//retrieve 1 user
module.exports.getUser = (userID) => {
    return User.findById(userID).then((user, err)=> {
        return (err)? true : false
    })
}

//create new user
module.exports.register = (userInfo) =>{
    let newUser = new User({
        firstName: userInfo.firstName,
        lastName: userInfo.lastName,
        email: userInfo.email,
        password: userInfo.password,
        isAdmin: userInfo.isAdmin,
        mobileNo: userInfo.mobileNo,
        enrollments: [
        {courseId: userInfo.courseId},
        {enrolledOn: userInfo.enrolledOn},
        {status: userInfo.status}
        ]
    })
    return newUser.save().then((user, err)=>{
        return (err) ? false : user
    })
}

//update user
module.exports.updateUser = (userUpdateInfo, userID) => {

    let userUpdates = {
        firstName: userUpdateInfo.firstName,
        lastName: userUpdateInfo.lastName,
        email: userUpdateInfo.email,
        password: userUpdateInfo.password,
        isAdmin: userUpdateInfo.isAdmin,
        mobileNo: userUpdateInfo.mobileNo,
        enrollments: [
            {courseId: userUpdateInfo.courseId},
            {enrolledOn: userUpdateInfo.enrolledOn},
            {status: userUpdateInfo.status}
        ]
    }

    const options = {
        new: true,
        upsert: true
    }

    return User.findByIdAndUpdate(userID, userUpdates, options).then((userUpdated, err) => {
        return (err) ? false : userUpdated
    })
    
}


//delete user
module.exports.delete = (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "User not found ",
            });
        }
        res.send({ message: "User deleted successfully!" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Could not delete user ",
        });
    });
};
```

html (form)

```
<form class="border border-secondary p-5 rounded-lg index-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login-email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="login-email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login-password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="login-password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="login">Log-in</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="register">Register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/14/nodejs-mongodb-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management .
Before you start connecting front end requests with back-end, you need to have a pretty good understanding on how things work in the back-end. One really good tool while developing and testing APIs is Postman. It will allow you to test those API points to make sure they work, before you start making those requests from your front-end. Also, I would recommend that you avoid the use of controllers when making those calls until you have a solid understanding of how things really work, and then later on, you can integrate those controllers in your routes.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the usual steps:**

> **1.** Send the password and email to the backend
>
> **2.** See if the email exist
>
> **NO**  then return invalid crednetials
>
> **YES** then check if password from front-end is the same as the
> database
>
> **3.** If password is the same then provide them a secret key (this is where the authorization kicks in so you need to decide whether you
> want to use **session_id** or **jwt**)

**This is what it would like in code in the backend**

```
module.exports.login = async(req,res) => {
  const {email, password} = req.body; // STEP 1

  let user = await User.findOne({email}) //STEP 2
 
  //checking if the user exist 
  if(!user){
    return res.send("Invalid Credentials");
  }
  
  //check if the password are the same
  if(user.password !== password){
    return res.send("Invalid Credentials");
  }

  //this is where you apply your session and jwt key
  res.send("LOGIN") //STEP 3


}
```

I recommend starting with JWT if you are new to the concept of authentication and authorization.